# Remove the unwanted breakpoints keeping the Important ones-Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I am developing a Website in Visual studio IDE. Once I executed the website having the debug point in the code. But after that even though I removed it multiple times when the code gets executed the the removed break point appears again. What can we do to remove the break point?

[image]

Comment: Click that line and push F9 this should remove it, maybe do a clean solution and rebuild if F9 doesnt work.  Also there is CTRL + SHIFT + F9 to remove all Breakpoints in a solution

Comment: I've noticed this behaviour in studio 2012 sometimes. And I use it for C++. From my experience, if you remove breakpoint while debugger **is not** running, it will go away, but if it's running, breakpoint will sometimes stay

Comment: Delete all breakpoints Ctrl+Shift+F9 While not actively running debugger

Comment: I've noticed in Visual Studio that if you remove a breakpoint while you are debugging that it will sometimes reappear the next time you run the debugger. However if you stop debugging before you remove it, then they don't come back.

Comment: @ Spo1ler Yes True this happens in 2012.. It is some times gets annoying for me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the menu ribbon, click on "Debug".
Click on "Windows" and select "Breakpoints".

A new window will open, and you can delete the 'stuck' (for lack of a better word)  breakpoints from there.

I prefer this solution because then at least you can remove the problematic breakpoints without getting rid of all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try "Ctrl" + "Shift" + "F9"
This will remove all the breakpoints from the current application.

Comment: Yes True this worked.I got this in VS 2012. And Seems like I removed them while I was debugging the application. So If we do like that It appears back.

Comment: Well if application is running but you are not debuggig it right now then it will permanently remove them.